# CHK graph dominance algorithm proof

Tags: algorithms, graphs, compilers

The algorithm developed by [Keith D. Cooper, Timothy J. Harvey, and Ken Kennedy](http://www.hipersoft.rice.edu/grads/publications/dom14.pdf) is widely used in industry for building dominator tree, but I cannot follow the proof in the “Engineering the data structure” section. Specifically, the claim of

> with this order, if $\operatorname{Dom}(a) ∩ \operatorname{Dom}(b) \neq ∅$, then the resulting set is a prefix of **both** $\operatorname{Dom}(a)$ and $\operatorname{Dom}(b)$.

How to prove that there are no situations like $\operatorname{Dom}(a)=[5,4,2,3,1]$ vs $\operatorname{Dom}(b)=[5,4,3,1]$?